# Why is this line branching as if the boolean condition resolves to true?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to use the VS debugger to discover the origin and cause of an error message ("Nullable object must have a value") that is arising from the bowels of a program which uses a third-party component, for which I have PDB files and source code files.

I am attaching a couple of screen-captures from the debugger session. Please note the tooltips showing the values of the variable contents. These are two separate screen-shots since I'm hovering over the variable.

I don't understand why, when `value` equals 1, and `CurrencyManager.Count` equals 2, the code is branching  to the line where `value` is reset to zero, as though  `value` < 0 or `value` >= 2.

Is this some sort of figment, where the debugger display isn't in sync with what is actually going on? If so, what can cause that sort of artefact and is there something I can do to fix it?

[image: debugger showing contents of value variable]

and here's the second one:

[image: debugger showing contents returned by Count]

and the Immediate Window:

[image: Immediate Window]

Comment: What does the `Count` property do, exactly? It couldbe a side-effect or another thread modifyng the values, if there are others.

Comment: What do you get in the immediate window if you paste the bool test in? And what of the individual parts? And what does value become of you step once?

Comment: @Alejandro:  `CurrencyManager` is a property of a Controller class (it's not my own code). Here is what is returned by a getter method: `return ((BindingContext)BindingContext)[DataSource, DataMember] as CurrencyManager;`.  The count is either the number of items in the datasource or the number of properties in the item. I am trying to track that down now.

Comment: there are many reasons why this happen. in release build the line number is usually wrong so the debugger will highlight the wrong line. Or if the program is obfuscated/IL optimized then the pdb might not be accurate either

Comment: @Caius Jard: In the Immediate Window the expression resolves to `false`. When I step through `value = 0`, the code jumps clean out of that setter method of the property and I find myself in another method inside a try block, having jumped over a couple of  lines inside the method, and I don't know how or why that jump happened.

Comment: Sounds like your source code isn't representative of the code being executed

Comment: Almost certainly a mismatch between source code and PDB. There's nothing you can do except get hold of source and PDB that are in sync from the third party - and even if you do, it will likely no longer match what your app has been built against.

Comment: Have you run the TPA through a debugger like ILSpy? Have you enabled "Break on thrown" for CLR exceptions? The PDB you have might at least be accurate for where the error originates/you might be able to trace what's unexpectedly null?

Comment: @Caius Jard: When I open Exceptions Settings in VS2019, I see a list of broad exception categories (C++, CLR, GPU, Java, Javascript several of these, Managed Debugging Assistants, WebKit, and Win32).  Above this list there is a read-only grid header that says "Break When Thrown".

Comment: I'd say then: forget the third party DLLs (chuck em out) and add their source as a project, reference it like you did do the DLL (before you chucked it out), get your VS to build their DLL again (so that it's all in sync), and put a tick next to CLR in that window. Run the app, cause the error and the debugger should stop the moment their code throws, so you can work backwards to find the true cause (bug in their code or garbage in from your side?)

Comment: @Caius Jard: Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Comment: @Perry Qian-MSFT : The company that produced the third-party component surmises that it is an artefact of their assemblies having been optimized. I've not yet been able to discover where the exception is being raised.  I am going to attempt to recompile their source at some point this week, but that is a daunting task.

Comment: @Tim, sure. And we will wait for your any feedback.